# Importing libraries from Artifactory to Lambda

Tags: python, aws-lambda, artifactory

I am developing a framework where non dev users can create a lambda and add custom events to eventbridge.

For this I have created a custom library which resides on Artifactory.

However, I am struggling with importing that library into lambda. I know that I can zip the lib and add it as a layer but that is not the right solution. I cannot expect a non-dev user to copy all those steps, rather I would like to give them a Jenkins job that they can deploy which automatically pulls the custom lib from Artifactory and creates a new lambda from the code they pass.

One solution I found was to add an `--extra-index-url https://artifactory.com/artifactory/api/<path to lib>/<lib name>/<version>/`

However, I keep getting the following error `ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement <lib name> == <lib version> (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for <lib name> == <lib version>`

Comment: Do you check this url with username and password `--extra-index-url https://USERNAME:PASSWORD@artifactory.com/artifactory/api/<path to lib>/<lib name>/<version>/`?